# Create field collection item in drupal 7

Tags: 7, entities

I am trying to dynamically create a field collection for a node.

Field collection item (field_markers) is used to create a point or a polygon for a map content type.

During debugging I found that my code create an entry for all the member elements of field collection but it does not create or update a record for field collection itself.

I have referred to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242018/dynamically-add-a-field-collection-in-drupal-7-by-script but was not able to resolve my problem.

Following is my code so far.

```
//Create field collection
$field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_markers'));

//Create fields related to field collection
$field_collection_item->field_title['und'][0]['value'] = "Brian 22";
$field_collection_item->field_summary['und'][0]['value'] = "Test entity creation.";
$field_collection_item->field_summary['und'][0]['format'] = "filtered_html";

$lat = -35.3241665257384;
$lon = 139.8046875;

$field_collection_item->field_coordinates['und'][0]['wkt'] = 'POINT ('.$lon.' '.$lat.')';
$field_collection_item->field_coordinates['und'][0]['geo_type'] = 'point';
$field_collection_item->field_coordinates['und'][0]['lat'] = $lat;
$field_collection_item->field_coordinates['und'][0]['lon'] = $lon;
$field_collection_item->field_coordinates['und'][0]['left'] = $lon;
$field_collection_item->field_coordinates['und'][0]['top'] = $lat;

$field_collection_item->field_coordinates['und'][0]['right'] = $lon;
$field_collection_item->field_coordinates['und'][0]['bottom'] = $lat;

//attach field collection to map content type
$field_collection_item->setHostEntity('map', $node);
// Save the entity.
$field_collection_item->save(TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, it was related to the workflow of content publishing (specific to my site ). Field collection item is created after a user with required permissions approve the content.

The code in question works and could be helpful for anyone else trying to create a field collection item containing a geofield.